# I want to compare a String that gets modified to its default

Tags: c#, string, csv, contains

I am writing a method to exclude metafields from a .csv file.

```
  public static string metaField(this string test)
    {
        String[] excludeMetafield = { "metafield_1000", "metafield_1001", "metafield_item_1_content_2", "metafield_short_description" };
        String testing = "";

        if (excludeMetafield.Contains(test) || excludeMetafield.Equals(test))
        {
            return test;
        }
        return testing = "Failed";
    }
```

When the `string test` gets passed into the method it is for example `"short_description"` but when the value is written to the .csv file it gets modified to `"metafield_short_description"`.

My `.Contains` is not detecting that `"metafield_short_description"` **CONTAINS** `"short_description"`. How can I do this?

Comment: This method is modified for testing to see if it detects when the String does contain that text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your currently checking if the array contains your exact value. You need to actually loop over your check strings and check if the iterated `String` physically contains your value.

```
  public static string metaField(this string test)
    {
        String[] excludeMetafield = { "metafield_1000", "metafield_1001", "metafield_item_1_content_2", "metafield_short_description" };
        String testing = "";

        foreach (string s in excludeMetafield) {
            if (s.Contains(test) || s.Equals(test))
            {
                return test;
            }
        }
        return testing = "Failed";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use linq

```
var excludeMetafield =  new string[] { "metafield_1000", "metafield_1001", "metafield_item_1_content_2", "metafield_short_description" };

if (excludeMetafield.Any(e=>e.Contains(test))) return test; 
return "Failed";
```